# saml2 not working with laravel socialite providers package

Tags: php, laravel, saml-2.0, laravel-socialite

My aim is to integrate an okta sso app that uses saml2 protocol. My project is built upon laravel and I'm using this [package](https://socialiteproviders.com/Saml2/) to help me integrate saml2. As per the docs I have implemented the following:

Added configuration to config/services.php

```
'saml2' => [
    'acs' => 'http://dashboard.test/okta-saml-callback',
    'entityid' => 'http://www.okta.com/exk7qiudmbjsr*******', 
    'certificate' => 'MIIDqDCCApCgAwIBAgIGAYU+Ux31MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG.......' 
  ]
```

Added provider event listener as such

```
protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // ... other providers
        \SocialiteProviders\Saml2\Saml2ExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
    ],
];
```

Added the authflow

```
Route::get('/okta-saml-login', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('saml2')->redirect();
})->name('saml.login');
```

And finally the callback URL

```
Route::get('/okta-saml-callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::driver('saml2')->user();
    dd($user);
});
```

After configuration, when I hit the '/okta-saml-login' route, instead of it redirecting me to the okta login pop up page for SSO, I get a 404 not found page. Which means there is something wrong with the auth URL. Now I tried to search the documentation but did not find anything about configuring auth URL anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a 404, make sure your callback URL is properly set. Some things to note:

1. Ensure your callback URL is set to `/auth/callback` which is the default.
2. If you are not doing number 1 and you want to use a custom callback like `/okta-saml-callback` then add it to your config like so:

> 'sp_acs' => 'okta-saml-callback',

3. Update this callback URL in your Okta dashboard and you are good to go.